# Telnet connection Procurve switch

Tags: linux, password, expect, telnet

Im writing a script to get a dump of the Procurve switch-settings

I start the script like this:

```
./script.sh | tee /home/user/telnet.log
```

Here the Script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 20
set  send_slow {5  .001}
set USERNAME "admin"
set PASSWORD "mypw"
spawn telnet 10.x.x.x
expect "Username: "
send "$USERNAME\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect "#"
send "show run\r"
send " "
send " "
send " "
interact
```

The send " " is to let it scroll down to the next page so i can catch the whole settings.

It works so far but im not able to quit the telnet session with the script
I tried to use send "exit \r"  but it doesnt work. Anyone an idea how i could quit it?

Also when i dont use the interact the password doesnt seem to get through. The script doesnt work then. Whats the deal with that? I have tried to use sleep that didnt help aswell.

Comment: Try sending the command `screen-length disable\r` so it won't ask you all the `MORE` questions.

Comment: While developing and expect script, add `exp_internal 1` near the top to enable verbose debugging. Very useful to see why your patterns aren't matching.

Comment: Also, a `.sh` extension for an expect script is misleading: use `.exp`

Comment: with screen-length disable\r i get invalid command. the exp_internal 1 is a good tip thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you need press space more or less than 3 times, you would do something like

```
expect {
    "Press space" {    # or whatever the pager prompt is
        send " "
        exp_continue;  # this "loops" back to the expect statement
    }
    "#"
}
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. It seems to get stuck after 1 or 2 spaces.To quit a "normal" connection to the Switch i have to write twice exit and confirm with yes. I tried to add another send exit and yes but didnt work either